# How to copy a file with systemd mount unit escape in name on cifs mount?

Tags: mount, samba, rsync, cifs, filename

I'm writing a backup with `rsync` and a file with the `systemd` mount unit escape `\x2d` for `-` on a `cifs` (protocol version 3) (`/mnt/diskstation/backup` in this example) causes the following trouble:

```
> sudo rsync -a /etc/systemd/system/ /mnt/diskstation/backup/test/
rsync: recv_generator: failed to stat "/mnt/diskstation/backup/test/snap-openmapper\x2ddesktop-22.mount": Invalid argument (22)
rsync: symlink "/mnt/diskstation/backup/test/multi-user.target.wants/snap-openmapper\x2ddesktop-22.mount" -> "/etc/systemd/system/snap-openmapper\x2ddesktop-22.mount" failed: Invalid argument (22)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1196) [sender=3.1.2]
```

Copying the file to `/tmp` with `sudo rsync -a /etc/systemd/system/ /tmp/test/` works fine.

Some more info about the file:

```
> stat /etc/systemd/system/snap-openmapper\\x2ddesktop-22.mount 
  Datei: /etc/systemd/system/snap-openmapper\x2ddesktop-22.mount
  Größe: 263        Blöcke: 8          EA Block: 4096   Normale Datei
Gerät: 802h/2050d   Inode: 2243        Verknüpfungen: 1
Zugriff: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Zugriff    : 2019-01-13 10:35:13.500148076 +0100
Modifiziert: 2018-06-30 21:10:57.316164101 +0200
Geändert   : 2018-08-02 13:54:58.150254417 +0200
 Geburt    : -
```

I'm wondering where the responsibility for this behaviour lies: user (`cifs` might have trouble allowing `\` in the name, but it's 2018, so...), `rsync` or `cifs`.